# javascript: displaying image according to select box value

Tags: javascript

In my program I have created select box and button. upon selecting different value from select box image should be displayed as shown in expected output. There are two buttons previous and next to change images. which should also work accordingly. I have created code below but my code is not working as per expectation. Can anyone help me ?

code:

```js
// counter
var i = 0;

// create object
imageObj = new Image(128, 128);

// set image list
images = new Array();
images[0] = "final_images/wcoat.jpg";
images[1] = "final_images/wcoat.jpg";
images[2] = "final_images/ktoys.jpg";
images[3] = "final_images/mixture.jpeg";
images[4] = "final_images/earing.jpg";

var imgLen = imageObj.length;

var go = document.getElementById('go');
go.addEventListener("click", loadItem);

function loadItem() {

  var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");

  var btnPre = document.createElement("input");
  //Assign different attributes to the element. 
  btnPre.type = "button";
  btnPre.value = "previous";
  btnPre.id = "preBtn";

  mainDiv.appendChild(btnPre);

  preBtn.addEventListener('click', prvs);

  var holder = document.getElementById("holder");

  if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "womens") {
    holder.src = images[0] + "<br>" + " Women's coat";
  } else if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "mens") {
    holder.src = images[1] + "<br>" + " Men's coat";
  } else if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "kids") {
    holder.src = images[2] + "<br>" + " Kid's toys";
  } else if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "mixture") {
    holder.src = images[3] + "<br>" + " Classic mixture";
  } else if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "earing") {
    holder.src = images[4] + "<br>" + " Gold Earing";
  }

  var btnNxt = document.createElement("input");
  //Assign different attributes to the element. 
  btnNxt.type = "button";
  btnNxt.value = "next";
  btnNxt.id = "nxtBtn";

  mainDiv.appendChild(btnNxt);

  nxtBtn.addEventListener('click', nxt);
}

function nxt() {
  if (i < imgLen - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }

  imageObj.src = images[i];
}

function prvs() {
  if (i > 0) {
    i--;
  } else {
    i = imgLen - 1;
  }
  imageObj.src = images[i];
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("final_images/back.jpg");
}

.container {
  /*width: 600px;*/
  /*height: 200px;*/
  border: inset;
  background-color: rgba(255, 234, 134, 0.9);
}

#selectBox {
  margin-left: 210px;
  width: 160px;
}

#below_hr {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#preBtn {
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-top: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container' id="main">
  <form name="myForm">
    <select name="mySelect" id="selectBox">
            <option value="womens">Women's coat</option>
            <option value="mens">Men's coat</option>
            <option value="kids">Kid's toys</option>
            <option value="mixture">Classic mixture</option>
            <option value="earing">Gold Earing</option>
           </select>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Go" id="go">
    </INPUT>
  </form>
  <HR size="4" color="red" id="hr">

  <div id="holder"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few tiny errors all adding up to this not working,  I'll try to remember and point them out. Here is a **working example with only 2 images** -you can fill yours back in

1. you have a div for your image "holder" this should be an `<img />`
   tag
2. `var imgLen = imageObj.length;` should be `var imgLen = images.length;` use the length of your array not the obj.
3. `preBtn.addEventListener` should be `btnPre.` `preBtn` doesn't exist
4. `holder.src = images[0] + "<br>" + " Women's coat";` the src attribute needs to be a valid url and you mess that up when you append `<br>` and a string to it.
5. `imageObj.src=images[i];` needs to reference your "holder" not `imageObj` so it should be `document.getElementById("holder").src = images[i];`
6. You don't need to dynamically put the next and previous buttons each image load (you aren't even clearing them) so the DOM keeps piling up with buttons.
7. You should use numbers as values so you can set the select to the correct description on next and prev
8. you need to keep track of i when the user jumps on the select (set i on the select change)

```js
// counter
var i = 0;

// create object
imageObj = new Image(128, 128);

// set image list
images = new Array();
images[0] = "https://cdn-image.myrecipes.com/sites/default/files/summer-sweet-lemonade-cl.jpg";
images[1] = "http://www.greatamericancookies.com/app/themes/greatamericancookies/library/images/home/carousel3.png";
images[2] = "final_images/ktoys.jpg";
images[3] = "final_images/mixture.jpeg";
images[4] = "final_images/earing.jpg";

var imgLen = images.length;

var go = document.getElementById('go');
var select = document.getElementById('selectBox');
var desc = document.getElementById('desc');
go.addEventListener("click", loadItem);

function loadItem() {
  var holder = document.getElementById("holder");

  if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == 0) {
    holder.src = images[0];
    desc.innerHTML = document.getElementById("select0").getAttribute("data-desc");
    i = 0;
  } else if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == 1) {
    holder.src = images[1];
    desc.innerHTML = document.getElementById("select1").getAttribute("data-desc");
    i = 1;
  } else if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == 2) {
    holder.src = images[2];
    desc.innerHTML = document.getElementById("select2").getAttribute("data-desc");
    i = 2;
  } else if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == 3) {
    holder.src = images[3];
    desc.innerHTML = document.getElementById("select3").getAttribute("data-desc");
    i = 3;
  } else if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == 4) {
    holder.src = images[4];
    desc.innerHTML = document.getElementById("select4").getAttribute("data-desc");
    i = 4;
  }
  document.getElementById('prev').style.display = "";
  document.getElementById('next').style.display = "";
}

function nxt() {
  if (i < imgLen - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  select.value = i;
  desc.innerHTML = document.getElementById("select" + i).getAttribute("data-desc");
  document.getElementById("holder").src = images[i];
}

function prvs() {
  if (i > 0) {
    i--;
  } else {
    i = imgLen - 1;
  }
  select.value = i;
  desc.innerHTML = document.getElementById("select" + i).getAttribute("data-desc");
  document.getElementById("holder").src = images[i];
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("final_images/back.jpg");
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  /*width: 600px;*/
  /*height: 200px;*/
  border: inset;
  background-color: rgba(255, 234, 134, 0.9);
}

#selectBox {
  margin-left: 210px;
  width: 160px;
}

#below_hr {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#preBtn {
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-top: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container' id="main">
  <form name="myForm">
    <select name="mySelect" id="selectBox">
        <option id="select0" data-desc="a womans coat" value=0>Women's coat</option>
        <option id="select1" data-desc="a mens winter coat" value=1>Men's coat</option>
        <option id="select2" data-desc="a kids toy to play with" value=2>Kid's toys</option>
        <option id="select3" data-desc="a classic mixture" value=3>Classic mixture</option>
        <option id="select4" data-desc="a beautiful gold earing" value=4>Gold Earing</option>
       </select>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Go" id="go">
    </INPUT>
  </form>
  <HR size="4" color="red" id="hr">

  <img id="holder" /><br/>
  <span id="desc"></span><br/><br/>
  
  <button id="prev" onclick="prvs()" style="display:none">Previous</button>
  <button id="next" onclick="nxt()" style="display:none">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I just edited it to provide more functionality like keeping the select in tune with the images on next and prev buttons

Comment: @Andreew I have one small concern. pre and next button should be only display after clicking on "go" button.

Comment: And also there should be description below each image.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a `data-desc` attribute you can add to the drop downs to include a description of the item

Comment: Button should be displayed only after clicking on go button

Comment: the prev and next buttons are hidden until user hits go

Comment: You made change. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157171/discussion-between-pari-and-andrew-lohr).

Answer (score 2):

You have quite a few errors inside your code, Andrew (+1 for that) already listed them in his  answer. 
But i think you maybe should also try to be more dynamic and create the selection from for example a configuration object.

Here's an example:

```js
// CLASS
var ImageSelector = (function(doc) {
  // private variables
  var _config,
      _selectionEl, 
      _imageEl,
      _prevBtnEl,
      _nextBtnEl,
      _currentIndex = 0;
  
  // constructor
  function ImageSelector(config) {
    var imageholderEl = doc.querySelector(config.imageholder);
    _config = config;
    _selectionEl = doc.querySelector(config.selection);
    _prevBtnEl = doc.querySelector(config.prevBtn);
    _nextBtnEl = doc.querySelector(config.nextBtn);
    if(!_selectionEl || !imageholderEl) {
      throw new Error('no selection or imageholder element found');
    }
    _imageEl = new Image();
    imageholderEl.appendChild(_imageEl);
    _generateSelection();
    _bindEvents();
  }
  
  // private methods
  function _generateSelection() {
    var fragment = doc.createDocumentFragment();
    var items = _config.items;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
      var item = items[i];
      var option = doc.createElement('option');
      option.value = item.value;
      option.textContent = item.name;
      fragment.appendChild(option);
    }
    _selectionEl.appendChild(fragment);
    _selectionEl.selectedIndex = _currentIndex;
  }

  function _loadImage() {
    var items = _config.items;
    var item = items.find(itm => itm.value === _selectionEl.value);
    _imageEl.src = item.image;
    _prevBtnEl.style.display = null;
    _nextBtnEl.style.display = null;
  }
  
  function _bindEvents() {
    var goBtnEl = doc.querySelector(config.goBtn);  
    _selectionEl.addEventListener('change', _loadImage);
    if(_prevBtnEl) {
      _prevBtnEl.addEventListener('click', ImageSelector.prototype.prev);
      _prevBtnEl.style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(_nextBtnEl) {
      _nextBtnEl.addEventListener('click', ImageSelector.prototype.next);
      _nextBtnEl.style.display = 'none';
    }   
    goBtnEl && goBtnEl.addEventListener('click', _loadImage)
  }
  
  function _changeIndex(direction) {
    var length = _config.items.length;
    _currentIndex = (_currentIndex + direction) % length;
    if(_currentIndex < 0) _currentIndex = length -1;
    _selectionEl.selectedIndex = _currentIndex;
    _selectionEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  }
  
  // public methods
  ImageSelector.prototype.next = function() {
    _changeIndex(1);
  }

  ImageSelector.prototype.prev = function() {
    _changeIndex(-1);
  }

  return ImageSelector;
})(document);


// CONFIGURATION
var config = {
  selection: '#selectBox',
  imageholder: '#holder',
  goBtn: '#go',
  prevBtn: '#prev',
  nextBtn: '#next',
  items: [
    { name: "Women's coat", value: "womens", image: "https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/562036/116906134/stock-photo-portrait-of-brown-eyed-cat-isolated-on-white-background-116906134.jpg" },
    { name: "Men's coat", value: "mens", image: "https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/154447/235089946/stock-photo-cute-little-red-kitten-sleeps-on-fur-white-blanket-235089946.jpg" },
    { name: "Kid's toys", value: "kids", image: "https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2288597/574871668/stock-photo-brown-cat-playing-relaxed-on-the-mobile-574871668.jpg" },
    { name: "Classic mixture", value: "mixture", image: "https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/4363153/520870675/stock-photo-lovely-cat-in-human-hands-vintage-effect-love-for-the-animals-520870675.jpg" },
    { name: "Gold Earing", value: "earing", image: "https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/428239/454556905/stock-photo-happy-scottish-kitten-looking-at-camera-isolated-on-white-background-454556905.jpg" }
  ]
}

// INITIALISATION
var selector = new ImageSelector(config);
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("final_images/back.jpg");
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  /*width: 600px;*/
  /*height: 200px;*/
  border: inset;
  background-color: rgba(255, 234, 134, 0.9);
}

#selectBox {
  margin-left: 210px;
  width: 160px;
}

#below_hr {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#preBtn {
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-top: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container' id="main">
  <form name="myForm">
    <select name="mySelect" id="selectBox">
      
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Go" id="go" />
  </form>
  <hr size="4" color="red" id="hr" />

  <div id="holder"></div>
  
  <button id="prev">Previous</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to display image on div tag.

Comment: Edited it ;) But fyi we're not a coding service, my code serves as an example how solving your problem could be achieved, which can be adapted further to fit your upcoming needs.

Comment: cool stuff cyrix. I tried keeping it the same as OP since he will understand it better, but this blows it out of the water! great job! +1