# Javascript : add images in div upon selecting value from select box

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying too add image inside dynamically created div. When user create go button it should create div element and image inside it according to value selected in select box. I have created div tag dynamically and created image object in order to get image. but in my code image is not loading inside div. can anyone help me to figure out issue ?

**CSS**

```
<style>

        body{
        background-image: url("final_images/back.jpg");
    }

    .container{
        /*width: 600px;*/
        /*height: 200px;*/
        border:inset;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 300px;
        margin-right: 190px;
        background-color:rgba(255, 234, 134, 0.9);
    }

    #selectBox{
        margin-left:  210px; 
        width: 160px;
    }

    #holder {

        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class = 'container' id="main">     
        <form name="myForm">
            <select name="mySelect" id="selectBox">
                <option value="womens">Women's coat</option>
                <option value="mens">Men's coat</option>
                <option value="kids">Kid's toys</option>
                <option value="mixture">Classic mixture</option>
                <option value="earing">Gold Earing</option>
            </select>    
            <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Go" id="go">
        </INPUT>
    </form>
    <HR size="4" color="red" id="hr">

    <!-- <div id="holder">  </div> -->
</div>   
 </body>
  </html>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>

         imageObj = new Image(128, 128);

         // set image list
         images = new Array();
         images[0]="final_images/wcoat.jpg";
         images[1]="final_images/wcoat.jpg";

        var go = document.getElementById('go');
        go.addEventListener("click", loadItem);

        function loadItem() {

            var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");

            var btnPre = document.createElement("input");
            //Assign different attributes to the element. 
            btnPre.type = "button";
            btnPre.value = "previous"; 
            btnPre.id = "preBtn";
            mainDiv.appendChild(btnPre);

            newdiv = document.createElement('div');   //create a div
            newdiv.id = 'holder';
            mainDiv.appendChild(newdiv); //add an id   


            var btnNxt = document.createElement("input");
            //Assign different attributes to the element. 
            btnNxt.type = "button";
            btnNxt.value = "next"; 
            btnNxt.id = "nxtBtn";

            mainDiv.appendChild(btnNxt);

            var holder = document.getElementById("holder");

            if(document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "womens"){
                holder.src = images[0] + " Women's coat";
            }  
            else if(document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "mens"){
                holder.src = images[1] + " Men's coat";
            }
        }

        </script>
```

Comment: Has this problem to be solved as a homework or something like that? Because that's almost the same question as this one (it's even the same CSS and HTML code): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858281/javascript-displaying-image-according-to-select-box-value

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an image tag instead of a div. You could also load images with CSS but thats probably not what you want.

starting on this line:

var holder = document.getElementById("holder");

```
  var image = new Image(128, 128);


  if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "womens") {
    image.src = images[0];
    holder.appendChild(image);
    holder.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Women's coat"));
  } else if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "mens") {
    image.src = images[1];
    holder.appendChild(image);
    holder.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Men's coat"));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A div is not an image container. Replace with `img` in the `createElement` fixes this.

Another big problem is the margins you use.

I've made a few adjustments

1. replaced `margin-left` with `float: right` for the select
2. put margin auto for left and right on the box.

```js
imageObj = new Image(128, 128);

// set image list
images = new Array();
images[0] = "final_images/wcoat.jpg";
images[1] = "final_images/wcoat.jpg";

var go = document.getElementById('go');
go.addEventListener("click", loadItem);

function loadItem() {

  var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");

  var btnPre = document.createElement("input");
  //Assign different attributes to the element. 
  btnPre.type = "button";
  btnPre.value = "previous";
  btnPre.id = "preBtn";
  mainDiv.appendChild(btnPre);

  newdiv = document.createElement('img'); //create a div
  newdiv.id = 'holder';
  mainDiv.appendChild(newdiv); //add an id


  var btnNxt = document.createElement("input");
  //Assign different attributes to the element. 
  btnNxt.type = "button";
  btnNxt.value = "next";
  btnNxt.id = "nxtBtn";

  mainDiv.appendChild(btnNxt);

  var holder = document.getElementById("holder");

  if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "womens") {
    holder.src = images[0] + " Women's coat";
  } else if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "mens") {
    holder.src = images[1] + " Men's coat";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("final_images/back.jpg");
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: inset;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 234, 134, 0.9);
}

#selectBox {
  float: right;
  width: 160px;
}

#holder {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class='container' id="main">
  <form name="myForm">
    <select name="mySelect" id="selectBox">
                <option value="womens">Women's coat</option>
                <option value="mens">Men's coat</option>
                <option value="kids">Kid's toys</option>
                <option value="mixture">Classic mixture</option>
                <option value="earing">Gold Earing</option>
            </select>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Go" id="go">
    </INPUT>
  </form>
  <HR size="4" color="red" id="hr" />

  <!-- <div id="holder">  </div> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate.
In the JavaScript code you are creating a div element here

```
newdiv = document.createElement('div');   //create a div
newdiv.id = 'holder';
mainDiv.appendChild(newdiv);
```

and then you are searching for element with Id **holder** and setting new image url.

```
var holder = document.getElementById("holder");
// holder is <div></div> element
if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "womens") {
    holder.src = images[0] + " Women's coat";
} else if (document.getElementById('selectBox').value == "mens") {
    holder.src = images[1] + " Men's coat";
}
```

> holder is a div tag now. it has no src attribute

But div element do not have attribute with name **src**. so the above code  will just add one more attribute to your div tag. but browser will not interpret it.

So if you want load image by setting **src** attribute, then you probably have to create holder as **img** tag which has attribute **src**. like this.

```
newdiv = document.createElement('img');   //create a img
newdiv.id = 'holder';
mainDiv.appendChild(newdiv);
```

> holder is a img tag. now it has src attribute

now it will work with no problem.